# jQuery validation: Total 100 in each row and each column

Tags: jquery, validation

I have the following table generated problematically based on DB data:

[image]

How to Sum each row and each Column and validate each of them to 100
the only Summation of 100 per each row and per each column is allowed to submit the form otherwise error message will appear next to <100 or >100 row or column
Save button is locked until data is correct.

**My Code:**

```
<style>
    table td{
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
<?php
    $course_id = $_GET['course_id'];
    $div_cou = explode(",",$course_id);
    $cou_id = $div_cou[0];
    $cou_name = $div_cou[1];

    $dbhost = "xxx";
    $dbuser = "xxx";
    $con    = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, "");
    if (!$con) {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    mysqli_select_db($con, 'xxx');

    $q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `plo` WHERE `COURSE_CODE`='$cou_id'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($q) !=null) {
        $plos = "<p style='color:#B3175D;'>Program Learning Outcome List:</p><ol>";
        $countPlos = 0;
        $plosArray = array();
        while ($db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
            $plos .= "<li>".$db_field['PLO_DESC']."</li>";
            $plosArray[$countPlos]['id']=$db_field['PLO_CODE'];
            $plosArray[$countPlos]['desc']=$db_field['PLO_DESC'];
            $countPlos++;
        }
        $plos .="</ol>";
    }
    echo $plos;

    $q = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `slo` WHERE `COURSE_CODE`='$cou_id'");
    if (mysqli_num_rows($q) !=null) {
        $slos = "<p style='color:#037879;'>Student Learning Outcome List:</p><ol>";
        $countSlos = 0;
        $slosArray = array();
        while ($db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
            $slos .= "<li style='list-style:decimal;'>".$db_field['SLO_DESC']."</li>";
            $slosArray[$countSlos]['id']=$db_field['SLO_CODE'];
            $slosArray[$countSlos]['desc']=$db_field['SLO_DESC'];
            $countSlos++;
        }
        $slos .="</ol>";
    }
    echo $slos;

    if ($countSlos)
    {
        $map = NULL;
        $map = "<p>Mapping SLO's to PLO's:</p><table>";

        $map .= "<tr><td></td>";
        $num = 1;
        for ($y = 0; $y < $countPlos; $y++) {
            $map .= "<td style='color:#B3175D;'>PLO".$num."</td>";
            $num++;
        }
        $map .="<td>Total</td></tr>";

        $num = 1;
        for ($x = 0; $x < $countSlos; $x++) { 
            $map .= "<tr><td style='color:#037879;'>SLO".$num."</td>";
            for ($y = 0; $y < $countPlos; $y++) {
                $map .= "<td><li style='list-style:none;'><input type='number' min='0' max='100' name='map[]' style='display: block;width: 50px;float: left;margin-right: 5px;text-align: left;'/><input type='hidden' name='sloPlo_ids[]' value='".$plosArray[$y]['id'].",".$slosArray[$x]['id']."'/></li></td>";
            }
            $map .="<td>Sum Row.</td>";
            $num++;
            $map .= "</tr>";
        }

        $map .="<tr><td>Total</td>";
        for ($y = 0; $y < $countPlos; $y++) {
            $map .="<td>Sum Col.</td>";
        }
        $map .="</tr>";
        echo $map."</table>";
    }
?>
```

Quick Link :
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Somayah/fvbn7mjp/)

Comment: im having headache reading your php, can you just paste the raw html?

Comment: Ok I will develop a fiddle

Comment: @SudarpoChong Can you check now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/sudarpochong/fghj7no4/1/

I made modification to your html.

To sum row and column, we just call `sumThisClass` method.
Please check my fiddle.

```
function sumThisClass(className) {

  var sumTotal = 0;
  $("." + className).each(function(index, el) {
    let elValue = parseInt($(el).val());
    if (!isNaN(elValue)) {
      sumTotal += parseInt($(el).val());
    }
  });

  $(".sum-" + className).text(sumTotal);

  if (sumTotal > 100) {
    $(".sum-" + className).append("<div class='error'>cannot be greater than 100</div>");
  }

}
```

Comment: Sir this line gives a red error in Dreamviewer ((let expectedTotal = $(".total").length * 100;)) ?

Comment: I replace every let with var and its working now .. Thanks

Comment: Oh ya, I am using chrome. Perhaps your browser does not support es6 :)

Comment: I'm sorry I was trying to change your way to make it work in my scenario. I have a problem if number of rows dose not = number of columns the calculations are not correct

Comment: It can be easily changed. You just need to modify some code.

Comment: Thanks I'll try my best ^^